# Ant 'fail unless' failing even though property exists

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I have an Ant script that is failing where it shouldn't.

properties file:

```
application.foo.name=foo
application.foo.path=[path-to-foo]
application.foo.file=foo.jar
appName=
```

code:

```
<target name="deploy_app" description="Deploys app">
  <condition property="appSelected">
    <and>
      <not>
        <equals arg1="${appName}" arg2="" />
      </not>
      <isset property="${appName}" />
    </and>
  </condition>

  <if>
    <equals arg1="${appSelected}" arg2="true" />
   <then>
    <!-- do nothing! -->
   </then>
   <else>
    <input
      message="Please enter application name:"
      addproperty="newAppName"
    />
    <var name="appName" value="${newAppName}" />
  </else>
</if>
  <antcall inheritAll="true" target="deploy" />
</target>

<target name="deploy">
    <echo message="Deploying from property: application.${appName}.file" />
  <propertycopy silent="true" name="appFile" from="application.${appName}.file" />
  <propertycopy silent="true" name="appPath" from="application.${appName}.path" />
  <echo message="appFile: ${appFile}" />
  <fail unless="${appFile}" message="appfile: ${appFile} No application with the name ${appName} is defined in your properties file." />
</target>
```

output:

```
 [echo] Deploying from property: application.foo.file
 [echo] appFile: foo.jar
ERROR: The following error occurred while executing this line:
appfile: foo.jar No application with the name foo is defined in your properties file.
```

It's even printing out the value of the property, but thinks it doesn't exist!

Any reason why?

Comment: It should be noted that the "if" and "propertycopy" tasks are part of a 3rd party ANT extension called ant-contrib.

Comment: Calling deploy here: <antcall inheritAll="true" target="deploy" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `unless` parameter for the `<fail>` command takes a property name, not a property value!

fixed version:

```
<fail unless="appFile" message="No application with the name ${appName} is defined in your properties file." />
```